# Build for ejs: ERR missing script build (npm run build)

Tags: express, npm, build, ejs, package.json

I'm trying to build my .ejs to deploy it but for 'npm run build' it says: npm ERR! Missing script: "build" I tryied a lot of lines in my package.json like this one:

```
"scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "build": "echo 'build script executed'"
  },
```

I don't know which is the correct script to build my ejs. I know that for react is  "build": "react-scripts build", but i dont know how it is for that other case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are mixing concepts, you dont actually need any build script if you are building a node express application